# How to overirde models.QuerySet.values method in the MYModel for alias fields?

Tags: django, django-models

How to override models.QuerySet.values method in the MYModel?
I want to reduce field name which is coming after values function called that function already written in  django.db.models.query.QuerySet.
I have logic which will written in function. I want to know that where I will override this function in models.py file?

Comment: Please share the code so that the question is more clear.

Comment: I want override QuerySet.values() function into custom created model class.